# how to remove excess 0 before the decimal point

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed this solution (http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/simple-formatting-in-a-cocoa-touch-text-edit-field-uitextfield/) and it works fine when I enter the first digit [result: "**0.01**"]. But when I enter the second digit the result is like this "**00.11**". It is adding another 0. How can make it to format my textfield into this "0.11" when I enter the second digit.

Here's my code

```
stringToFormat = [stringToFormat stringReplacingOccurenceOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [GLobalSettings getCurrency]] withString @""]; // remove currency
NSString normalizedString = stringToFormat;
normalizedString = [normalizedString stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString"@"." withString:@""]; // remove dot
if(normalizedString.length <= 2)
{
    normalizedString = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.2f", [normalizedString floatValue]/100.0];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [GlobalSettings getCurrency], normalizedString];

}
```

any help would be much appreciated...thanks..

Comment: YOY are you doing this: `[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.2f",...`??

Comment: And why are you doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [GLobalSettings getCurrency]]`?

Comment: And it wouldn't hurt if you added some comments to your code, to explain what you think you are doing.

Comment: Gad!  Your reference uses that `[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:...` statement and he's passing himself off as an expert???